# Okay, Unzip Jar, Zip Jar Success! But unzipping it again Fails?

Tags: java, jar, zip, unzip

Title says all, Although in the Java Unzipping method it closes and gives this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ##File hierarchy here#\armor (Access is denied)
```

But if I try to unzip with 7-zip i get these errors:

```
Error: can not delete ouput file: ##File hierarchy here#\armor
```

For every folder in the Jar,Which means it must be a problem with my zipping method - I hope I'm making sense!

Steps I took:
1. Unzipped the jar with success
2. Zipped the jar with success
3. Unzipped again to find all those errors.

Here's my zipping method:

```
package minecraftmodmanager;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarOutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Tom
 */
public class jarZip {

    public static void zipAll(File Directory, File jar) {
        try {
            JFrame.debugLn("Opening Jos: " + jar.getName() + "... ");
            JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jar));
            zip(Directory, "", jos);
            jos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(jarZip.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public static void zip(File Directory, String Hierarchy, JarOutputStream jos) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream in = null;
            File[] directoryFiles = Directory.listFiles();
            JFrame.debug("JOS Opened!");
            System.out.println();

            String FullDirectoryPath = Directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
            String BasePath = FullDirectoryPath.substring(0, FullDirectoryPath.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);
            JFrame.debug("BasePath: " + BasePath);

            for (int FileNumber = 0; FileNumber < directoryFiles.length; FileNumber++) {

                String name = directoryFiles[FileNumber].getPath();
                String JarFileName = name.replace(BasePath, "");
                String FullFileHierarchy = Hierarchy + JarFileName;

                if (directoryFiles[FileNumber].isDirectory()) {
                    zip(directoryFiles[FileNumber], FullFileHierarchy + "/", jos);
                }

                JFrame.debug("name: " + FullFileHierarchy);
                JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(FullFileHierarchy);
                jos.putNextEntry(entry);
                if(!directoryFiles[FileNumber].isDirectory()) {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(directoryFiles[FileNumber]));

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while (true) {
                    int count = in.read(buffer);
                    if (count == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    jos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                jos.closeEntry();
            } else {
                 jos.closeEntry();
            }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(jarZip.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciated guys! Kinda new here so 'scuse me if I haven't followed and rules

Comment: You can start with writing minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I would *guess* that maybe another process has opened the file handles of the unzipped files (from the first unzipping).  When you try to unzip again, the target files already exist and must be deleted - but since a separate process has them locked, access is denied for this delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but I think your problem might be that you are trying to jar the actual folders. You don't need to -- when it comes time to extract the files, the unzipper or unjarrer will make the folders based on the paths of the jar or zip entries.

If you add a continue where you call `zip` on subdirectories,  like

```
    if (directoryFiles[FileNumber].isDirectory()) {
                zip(directoryFiles[FileNumber], FullFileHierarchy + "/", jos);
                continue;
            }
```

This ought to recursively add your files, while not adding the folders.

While you did check to make sure you only try reading from files, you still were attempting to push folders into the `JarOutputStream`

```
            JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(FullFileHierarchy);
            jos.putNextEntry(entry);
            if(!directoryFiles[FileNumber].isDirectory()) {
```

The JarOutputStream thought you were making a file that had no contents at all, and was named the same name as one of your folders. So when it comes time to unzip, it creates both a folder AND a file with the same name.

If this works for you, you can probably revise the rest of your code accordingly.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: That was it, although I had already solved it, Thanks for taking the time guys! :)